# How to replace a char in an an char array? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, char, exc-bad-access

i got the following *char array* in **Objective-C (Xcode)**:

```
char *incomeMessage;


NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes length:data.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
incomeMessage = [str UTF8String];

NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[0]);
NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[1]);
NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[2]);
NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[3]);
NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[4]);
NSLog(@"%c", incomeMessage[5]);
```

For example I get some results like this in console:

```
"3
 2
 6
 1
 8
 4"
```

Now i want to replace the char in incomeMessage[2] by 4:

```
incomeMessage[2] = '4';
```

But then it gives me the error:
EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Do you have an idea, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String), `UTF8String` returns a read-only (`const char*`) reference to the string data.

The reference material goes on to note:

> This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object,
>   which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will
>   certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C
>   string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which
>   you use this property.

So I'd suggest following their advice and creating a copy of the array and then performing your modifications against that.

For example:  http://ideone.com/mhjwZW

You might have better luck with something like:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes length:data.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char* incomeMessage = malloc([str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1);
strcpy(incomeMessage, [str UTF8String]);

//now you can change things    
incomeMessage[2] = '4';

//do this when you're done
free(incomeMessage);
```

Although, is there any particular reason why you want to use a C-string/character array as opposed to an `NSMutableString`?  I think you might find [replaceCharactersInRange:withString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) a better approach generally.  See also:  [stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:).

Comment: Yes, I was playing with the ideone while you were posting, apparently.  I tend to forget that SO is less about providing a complete answer than it is about providing a fast answer and then editing it to be more complete.

Comment: You should copy your `ideaone` code into the answer. Links can break. Your answer will be _better_ than mine if you add code. I'm not going to add any code to mine. :) Go for it.

Comment: I just want to add that [str length] can be different than the size of [str UTF8String]. [str length] return the num of Unicode characters in str. You have to use -[NSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:].

Answer (score 2):

> i got the following char array in Objective-C (Xcode)

You don't, you know. All you have is a pointer. You have not set aside any actual memory; there is no array there.

```
incomeMessage = [str UTF8String];
```

All you've done in that line is repoint the pointer `incomeMessage` at your string's `UTF8String`. A string's `UTF8String` is immutable. Note this passage in the docs:

> you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property.

So basically, if you want to write into an array of `char`, your first task should be to *make* an array of `char`.